# Updating a column automatically, when another column is updated in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Table Name:User_table

```
Uname       pwd          expire_date          update_pwd_date
-------------------------------------------------------------
aaa         aaa          30-AUG-2013           null
bbb         bbb          01-SEP-2013           null
ccc         ccc          15-sep-2013           null
ddd         ddd          29-SEP-2013           null
```

So when we are going to update `pwd` column, it should automatically update `update_pwd_date` column with current date(sysdate).

I want output like:

```
Uname       pwd          expire_date          update_pwd_date
-------------------------------------------------------------
aaa         eee          30-AUG-2013           23-AUG-2013
bbb         fff          01-SEP-2013           23-AUG-2013
ccc         ggg          15-sep-2013           23-AUG-2013
ddd         hhh          29-SEP-2013           23-AUG-2013
```

Actually i am trying to use below trigger.But it's not working.

```
create or replace trigger user_trg
before update of pwd
on user_tab
for each row
declare
Pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
update user_tab set pas_update=sys date where pwd=:new.pwd;
commit;
end;
```

---

Actually i am trying to below trigger.But it's not working.

create or replace trigger user_`trg`
before  update of `pwd` on user_tab
for each row
declare
`Pragma`  autonomous_transaction;
begin
update user_tab  set pas_update=`s`y`s` date where `p`w`d`=:`n`e`w`.p`w`d`;
commit;
end;

Please anybody can give solution for this query?

Answer (score 2):

I think the other answers will give you what you need for the trigger.

I dislike triggers. A lot. Not that they don't work, it's that they are often overlooked or dependencies forgotten about. Shorter, they are the devil.

Maybe I can convince you to try it a different way.

You're already writing PL/SQL, why not just create an API (package)? It's pretty simple actually.

```
create or replace
package maintain_user_table
as
  procedure update_user_pwd( p_uname in varchar2, p_new_pwd in varchar2 );
end;
/
```

Assumptions:
1. uname is a PK

```
create or replace
package body maintain_user_table
as
  procedure update_user_pwd( p_uname in varchar2, p_new_pwd in varchar2 )
  is
  begin
    --error checking can go here
    update user_table
      set pwd = p_new_pwd
        update_pwd_date = SYSDATE
    where uname = p_uname;

    if sql%rowcount = 1 then
      --update successful
    else if sql%rowcount = 0 then
      --no rows found
    else
      --more than one row updated, not good, probably rollback or something
    end if;
  end update_user_pwd;
end;
/
```

This will allow you to more tightly control the quality of your data. Leaving a particular table open to UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE from anything but this procedure means you are just *hoping* that everyone follows this particular rule (which is why the trigger is necessary). Remove the trigger. Close down access to this table and force people/applications to use the PL/SQL API.

Just something to consider...

Answer (score 1):

If you are updating a column in the same table/row which is getting updated, then you shouldn't use UPDATE statement. Simply, set the column with the new value.

```
:new.update_pwd_date := sysdate;
```

Also, there is no need for pragma autonomous transaction or COMMIT.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
TRIGGER user_trg 
     BEFORE UPDATE OF pwd ON user_tab 
     FOR EACH row 
BEGIN
     :new.update_pwd_date := sysdate;
END;
```